# Xhost: Unable to open display (setting up Vino on VPS)

Tags: server, graphics, vnc, vino

I'm currently trying to setup Vino (the VNC server) on a VPS of mine. However, whenever I try exporting and opening the display, it doesn't work. I've looked for hours last night for a solution for this, but I've read everything I can find, and still it doesn't seem to help. The part that seems to be having problems:

```
joe@ubuntu12:~$ vino-preferences

(vino-preferences:1513): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_entry_set_text: assertion `text != NULL' failed
joe@ubuntu12:~$ sudo -s
[sudo] password for joe: 
root@ubuntu12:~# export DISPLAY=:0.0
root@ubuntu12:~# xhost +
xhost:  unable to open display ":0.0"
root@ubuntu12:~# top
```

Based on this (I know it's from 2006): http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=266981

Vino preferences opens (using my remote computer, which is also running ubuntu) despite the error.

I've tried installing Ubuntu Desktop (as well as all the other things people have suggested - excluding VNC servers, I skipped people saying to use things other than Vino, in order to avoid conflicts. Early on I installed VNC4Server, but that was quickly removed again using apt.)

Anyone got any ideas? it's running Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS (Server).